# build newest mavlink(2015.12.12) in ros indigo

Tags: ros, mavlink, catkin, build

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I try to build newest **mavlink (2015.12.12)** and **mavros (0.16.3)** in odroid xu4 installed ubuntu 14.04 and ros indigo followed [mavros source installation](https://github.com/mavlink/mavros/blob/master/mavros/README.md#installation).
I am using `catkin build` from **catkin_tools** to build those packages. After build successfully and source environments for sure.
And I can `roscd mavros`  go to `PATH/src/mavros/mavors`.
but `roscd mavlink` just go to old one in `opt/ros/indigo/share/mavlink`.
Any suggestions will be appreciate.

**printenv | grep ROS:**

```
ROS_ROOT=/opt/ros/indigo/share/ros
ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/home/odroid/Skywalker/src/mavros/mavros_msgs:/home/odroid/Skywalker/src/mavros/libmavconn:/home/odroid/Skywalker/src/mavros/mavros:/home/odroid/Skywalker/src/mavros/mavros_extras:/home/odroid/Skywalker/src/mavros/test_mavros:/opt/ros/indigo/share:/opt/ros/indigo/stacks
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311
ROSLISP_PACKAGE_DIRECTORIES=/home/odroid/Skywalker/devel/share/common-lisp
ROS_DISTRO=indigo
ROS_ETC_DIR=/opt/ros/indigo/etc/ros
```

**catkin config:**

```
Profile: default
Extending: [cached] /opt/ros/indigo
Workspace: /home/odroid/Skywalker
Source Space: [exists] /home/odroid/Skywalker/src
Build Space: [exists] /home/odroid/Skywalker/build
Devel Space: [exists] /home/odroid/Skywalker/devel
Install Space: [missing] /home/odroid/Skywalker/install
DESTDIR: None

Isolate Develspaces: False
Install Packages: False
Isolate Installs: False

Additional CMake Args: None
Additional Make Args: None
Additional catkin Make Args: None
Internal Make Job Server: True

Whitelisted Packages: None
Blacklisted Packages: None

Workspace configuration appears valid.
```

**catkin_find mavlink:**

```
/home/odroid/Skywalker/devel/include/mavlink
/home/odroid/Skywalker/devel/share/mavlink
/opt/ros/indigo/include/mavlink
/opt/ros/indigo/share/mavlink
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/222484/build-newest-mavlink(2015.12.12)-in-ros-indigo/) by [crazymumu](https://answers.ros.org/users/21710/crazymumu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 214 on 2015-12-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Actually, the **mavlink** package was build successfully. Maybe that package is not **catkin package** so that could't find by **roscd**. Thanks all.

---

Originally posted by [crazymumu](https://answers.ros.org/users/21710/crazymumu/) with karma: 214 on 2016-01-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0